# Rename all column names by adding a string in KQL/Kusto/Data Explorer

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I am joining 2 tables which both have hundreds of similarly named columns.  I would like to change all of the column names in each table to include the table name.  To keep the query simple, I **do not** want to call out each column name explicitly.  Is there a way to append the table name to all column names without explicitly calling out each column?

For example:

```
let T1 = datatable (Key:string , Col2:string , Col3:string )[
"1", "b", "c",
"2", "e", "f",
"3", "h", "i"];
let T2 = datatable (Key:string , Col2:string , Col3:string )[
"1", "B", "C",
"2", "E", "F",
"4", "H", "I"];
T1 | join T2 on Key
```

**Result:**

```
Key Col2 Col3 Key1 Col21 Col31
1   b    c    1    B     C
2   e    f    2    E     F
```

**Desired Result:**

```
T1.Key T1.Col2 T1.Col3 T2.Key T2.Col2 T2.Col3
1      b       c       1      B       C
2      e       f       2      E       F
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the order of columns is not important to you, then this would be one way to do it:

```
let T1 = datatable (Key:string , Col2:string , Col3:string )
[
  "1", "b", "c",
  "2", "e", "f",
  "3", "h", "i"
] 
| project PackedRecord = todynamic(replace_regex(tostring(pack_all()), '"([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)":"', @'"T1_\1":"'))
| evaluate bag_unpack(PackedRecord);
let T2 = datatable (Key:string , Col2:string , Col3:string )
[
  "1", "B", "C",
  "2", "E", "F",
  "4", "H", "I"
] 
| project PackedRecord = todynamic(replace_regex(tostring(pack_all()), '"([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)":"', @'"T2_\1":"'))
| evaluate bag_unpack(PackedRecord);
let JoinTable = T1 | join kind=inner T2 on $left.T1_Key == $right.T2_Key;
JoinTable
```

Result:

| T1_Col2 | T1_Col3 | T1_Key | T2_Col2 | T2_Col3 | T2_Key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| b | c | 1 | B | C | 1 |
| e | f | 2 | E | F | 2 |

If you want to reorder the columns, you can use [project-reorder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/projectreorderoperator).

Comment: The answer above works, however, it is pretty slow when we apply it to larger data sets.  Is there a way to achieve this without packing the whole dataset?

Comment: @PorgtheEaten You can use project-rename to simply rename the columns either before or after the join to your desired format. Depending on how many columns you have it possibly quite a bit of typing work but will be a lot faster to execute.