# Change name of all columns based on table names (KQL / Kusto / Azure Data Explorer)

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I am joining 2 tables which both have hundreds of similarly named columns. I would like to change all of the column names in each table to include the table name. To keep the query simple, I do not want to call out each column name explicitly. The query below accomplishes this goal.  However, the below query is extremely slow when applied to large datasets.  I assume that the slow performance is due to the fact that the replace_regex() function is running on the entire dataset. Is there another way to achieve the same result while improving performance on larger datasets?

```
let T1 = datatable (Key:string , Col2:string , Col3:string )
[
  "1", "b", "c",
  "2", "e", "f",
  "3", "h", "i"
] 
| project PackedRecord = todynamic(replace_regex(tostring(pack_all()), '"([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)":"', @'"T1_\1":"'))
| evaluate bag_unpack(PackedRecord);
let T2 = datatable (Key:string , Col2:string , Col3:string )
[
  "1", "B", "C",
  "2", "E", "F",
  "4", "H", "I"
] 
| project PackedRecord = todynamic(replace_regex(tostring(pack_all()), '"([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)":"', @'"T2_\1":"'))
| evaluate bag_unpack(PackedRecord);
let JoinTable = T1 | join kind=inner T2 on $left.T1_Key == $right.T2_Key;
JoinTable
```

**Previous Question for Reference**

[Rename all column names by adding a string in KQL/Kusto/Data Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69855410/rename-all-column-names-by-adding-a-string-in-kql-kusto-data-explorer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same results without using `replace_regex()` and relying on `OutputColumnPrefix` while doing the `bag_unpack` operation. Modified a couple of lines from your original kql snippet.

Based on the kusto documentation the `OutputColumnPrefix` argument allows passing a common prefix to add to all columns produced by the plugin.

```
let T1 = datatable (Key:string , Col2:string , Col3:string )
[
  "1", "b", "c",
  "2", "e", "f",
  "3", "h", "i"
]
| project Key, PackedRecord = pack_all()
| evaluate bag_unpack(PackedRecord, OutputColumnPrefix = "T1_") | project-away T1_Key; // get rid of additional key;
let T2 = datatable (Key:string , Col2:string , Col3:string )
[
  "1", "B", "C",
  "2", "E", "F",
  "4", "H", "I"
]
| project Key, PackedRecord = pack_all()
| evaluate bag_unpack(PackedRecord, OutputColumnPrefix = "T2_") | project-away T2_Key; // get rid of additional key;
T1 
| join kind=inner T2 on $left.Key == $right.Key | project-away Key1 // get rid of second key after join
```

Comment: degant,  this is awesome!  At a minimum, this cleans up the query considerably.  Also, appears to be improving performance as well.  Thank you!